# enable range-based loops for gcc 4.9.3

Tags: c++, loops, gcc

I maintain a code base that is required to compile with a wide range of c++ backends, the oldest of which is gcc 4.9.3.

For the newer versions, some of the libraries have now switched to only allowing range-based loops, which puts me in the tough situation that I have to maintain a codebase that uses range-based loops and is still required to compile successfully with older versions where support for range-based loops was not widespread.

Notably, attempting to compile the current version using range-based loops in gcc 4.9.3 leads to error messages of this type:

```
error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
error: 'end' was not declared in this scope
```

Is there some way I can monkeypatch the codebase to include custom definitions of `begin` and `end` that will work with gcc 4.9.3, or is this a lost cause?

**Details**

Since additional details were requested in the comments, here's the full story.

The backend library we rely on is CERN's ROOT framework.
ROOT, and specifically the component RooFit has a lot of custom container types (`RooArgSet`, `RooArgList`, `RooLinkedList`, ...) for which range-based loops have been added over the last years (ROOT 6.18 and forward, I believe), to a large part by modifying the containers in so far that they now use stl backends in many places.

Our pipeline uses a lot of different ROOT versions to test, so we already have overloads defined for many of these containers in a way similar to the following:

```
#if ROOT_VERSION_CODE < ROOT_VERSION(6,18,0)

struct RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper { //EXCLUDE
  RooFIter itr;
  RooAbsArg* nextItem;
  RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper(const RooAbsCollection& c, bool end);
  RooAbsArg* operator++();
  bool operator!=(const RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper& other);
  bool operator!=(const RooAbsArg* other);
  RooAbsArg* operator*();
};
RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper begin(const RooAbsCollection& c);
RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper end(const RooAbsCollection& c); 
RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper::RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper(const RooAbsCollection& c, bool end) : itr(c.fwdIterator()), nextItem(end ? NULL : itr.next()) {}
RooAbsArg* RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper::operator++(){ nextItem = itr.next(); return nextItem; }
bool RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper::operator!=(const RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper& other){ return this->nextItem != other.nextItem; }
bool RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper::operator!=(const RooAbsArg* other){  return this->nextItem != other; }
RooAbsArg* RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper::operator*(){ return nextItem; }
RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper begin(const RooAbsCollection& c){
  return RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper(c,false);
}
RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper end(const RooAbsCollection& c){
  return RooAbsCollection_IteratorHelper(c,true);
}
#endif
```

However, for the very old versions (ROOT 6.04.16, specifically), this leads to error messages like this one:

```
/builds/cburgard/RooFitUtils/Root/AbsMeasurement.cxx:264:19: error: 'end' was not declared in this scope
     for (auto* it:pars){
                   ^
/builds/cburgard/RooFitUtils/Root/AbsMeasurement.cxx:264:19: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/Gcc/gcc493_x86_64_slc6/slc6/x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/basic_string.h:42:0,
                 from /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/Gcc/gcc493_x86_64_slc6/slc6/x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/include/c++/4.9.3/string:52,
                 from /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/Gcc/gcc493_x86_64_slc6/slc6/x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/Gcc/gcc493_x86_64_slc6/slc6/x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/Gcc/gcc493_x86_64_slc6/slc6/x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/include/c++/4.9.3/ios:42,
                 from /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/Gcc/gcc493_x86_64_slc6/slc6/x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/include/c++/4.9.3/ostream:38,
                 from /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/Gcc/gcc493_x86_64_slc6/slc6/x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/include/c++/4.9.3/iostream:39,
                 from /builds/cburgard/RooFitUtils/RooFitUtils/AbsMeasurement.h:5,
                 from /builds/cburgard/RooFitUtils/Root/AbsMeasurement.cxx:1:
/cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/Gcc/gcc493_x86_64_slc6/slc6/x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/include/c++/4.9.3/initializer_list:99:5: note:   'std::end'
     end(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
```

At this point, I'm a little bit lost - is gcc 4.9.3 really just missing the `begin` and `end` functions? Did they move namespace? Am I missing some crucial `#include`?

Comment: you can provide the missing overloads for `begin` and `end` (they need to be findable via ADL or be member functions afair)

Comment: what overloads are missing? Please include more information. Whether this can be patched depends on what container you are trying to iterate

Comment: Range-based for loops work perfectly fine on GCC 4.9.3: https://godbolt.org/z/77Y7Kssxe (And `begin`/`end` are normally provided as member functions, so some of your types are likely missing a member `begin`/`end` only in older versions of GCC)

Comment: thanks for all the input, I've updated the question to include more details!

Comment: These newfangled languages are up to no good. Physicists should have sticked with FORTRAN.

Comment: [see defect section CWG 1442](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), it was UB to depend on unqualified lookup of begin / end at some point.

Comment: @haleyk no. unspecified is not undefined. There is a crucial difference between those two

Comment: please show a [mre], what is `pars`? Does it have `begin()`/`end()` methods or a specialisation of `std::begin()`/`std::end()`?

Comment: @Artyer: your comment made me realize that the problem I was actually facing was just that of a missing "#include". Thanks a lot!